# How to restore .dump or .sql on Azure PostgreSQL Server

Tags: postgresql, azure, psql, pgadmin, navicat

I already have .dump and .sql but I am unable to restore it.
I used pgAdmin, i can see the tables but there are no data in it.Same thing in Azure Studio and Navicat.
I use "pg_restore" to restore the file but it doesn't throw any error.

Comment: Which problem/error did you get?

Comment: How did you get the `.dump` and `.sql` files?  You have two files, but you only mention restoring "it" or "the", singular.  If you only restore one, which one did you restore?  If both, in which order and how?  You mention multiple attempts, did you reset the database between attempts?

Comment: I took the backup of database in .sql and .dump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Right way to take a dump with data and restore is

```
./pg_dump -U postgres -p 5432 -h <remote_IP> -Ft dbname_source > dump_of_source.sql.tar 
./pg_restore -U postgres -h localhost -p 5432 -d dbname_target dump_of_source.sql.tar
```